# How to setup type definition for an Apollo error response

Tags: javascript, typescript, apollo

Apollo [describes](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#graphql-error-policies) that an error response can look like this

```json
{
  "data": {
    "getInt": 12,
    "getString": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Failed to get string!",
      // ...additional fields...
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I import the type(script) definition of this response?

Imagine the type def. would be something like:

```js
type ApolloError = {
  data?: {
    getInt?: number,
    getString?: string | null
  },
  errors: { message: string, ... }[]
}
```

I imagine it would go something like

```js
import type { Error } from 'some-apollo'
```

or would a some dev package like '@types/apollo` do it globally?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković google also gave me this site.. What did you find useful on it?

Answer (score 3):

On the client?

There's already a type defintion for ApolloError in the client.

`import { ApolloError } from '@apollo/client/errors';`

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/main/src/errors/index.ts

Comment: Yes, on the client